# Sort product listings in Spree based on created_at

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, spree

I'm using spree and I want to sort product listing based on `created_at` of the product.

I tried to find the way to override the spree default scope under **lib/scopes/product.rb** but couldn't find it.

I want to list recently created products on public panel. How can I do it with spree?

Answer (score 14):

First answer will break admin panel product edition and maybe other stuff in spree 1.1-stable.

> ambiguous column name: created_at

You may fix this by specifying the table name with :

```ruby
 Product.class_eval do
    default_scope order("spree_products.created_at DESC")
 end
```

But I think best solution would be to patch the public products controller or view, not the model itself as the default_scope may not be expected everywhere and to switch/remove an order defined in a default_scope you must call **.re**order()

Probably because of this, SpreeCommerce documentation specifically do not recommend you add order in product scopes :

Source : http://guides.spreecommerce.com/scopes_and_groups.html#modifying-available-scopes

So I think the proper way of doing this without screwing the Spree core product model is to overwrite the products template :

Overwrite **views/spree/shared/_products.html.rb**

replace

```ruby
 <% products.each do |product| %>
```

with

```
 <% products.descend_by_updated_at.each do |product| %>
```

Source : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/spree-user/lW5sGsbMTfM

Works for me™

Comment: This can be handled a little bit more granularly with a deface override rather than overriding the entire view, but it seems like this answer is more informed than the one marked as accepted.